# SwiftUI search scope on macOS

Tags: search, swiftui, scope

I try to use search scopes in SwiftUI.

```
        NavigationSplitView {
            RoundsListView(viewModel: RoundsListViewModel(repElem: self.search))
            #if os(tvOS)
                .searchable(text:       searchText,
                            placement:  .automatic)
            #else   //  not tvOS (iOS, macOS, Catalyst)
                .searchable(text:       searchText,
                            placement:  .sidebar)
                .searchScopes(searchScope) {
                    Text("All").tag(Search.Scope.all)
                    Text("Entry").tag(Search.Scope.entry)
                }
            #endif
            #if os(iOS)
                .navigationBarTitle("Search", displayMode: .inline)
            #endif
        }   detail: {
            EmptyView()
        }
```

It works fine in iOS (though the scopes only show when there is a text in the search field, which could be seen as strange), but I can't get to have those scope buttons on macOS, should that be directly on macOS or Catalyst on Mac.

[image]

How to get the scope buttons on Mac ?